# invalid type argument of unary '*' (have 'uint8_t {aka unsigned char}')

Tags: arduino-uno-wifi

New to Arduino and was hoping to figure this out. I am working with a bill acceptor and getting the value once you insert the money. The code works fine with an older Arduino, but I am using Arduino Uno Wifi Rev2 and getting some major issues. I finally go it down to just this error and i cant figure this one out (Help Please!):

```
invalid type argument of unary '*' (have 'uint8_t {aka unsigned char}')
```

On line:

```
*digitalPinToPCMSK(_receivePin) |= _BV(digitalPinToPCMSKbit(_receivePin));
```

Library that is giving the issue:

ReceiveOnlySoftwareSerial

Comment: You have to familiarise yourself with pointers if you want to use '*'. Also, edit your post and add more of your code.

Comment: What are you trying to do with this? Please provide more of your code and an explanation about your indents with it.

Comment: @chrisl this is code that already exists out there, i am just trying to use it on a newer board. The library ReceiveOnlySoftwareSerial is producing this error. I dont want to post the whole code in here but you can find the code here http://gammon.com.au/Arduino/ReceiveOnlySoftwareSerial.zip